# Dart Errors in multi-level asynchronous code

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Consider the following code

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future main() async {
  try {
    print("trying");
    await doSomething();
    print("success");
  } catch (e) {
    print("caught");
  }
}

Future<int> doSomething() async {
  await doSomethingElse();
  return 5;
}

Future<int> doSomethingElse() async {
  throw new Exception();
}
```

When run, the exception thrown in `doSomethingElse()` is caught up in `main()`, and everything works as expected. But, say the person who wrote the `doSomething()` method didn't realize that `doSomethingElse()` was asynchronous, and instead wrote the follow (note the missing `await`).

```dart
Future<int> doSomething() async {
  doSomethingElse();
  return 5;
}
```

Now the exception isn't caught at all. Rather, the output now looks like this:

```dart
trying
success
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Exception
Stack Trace:
#0      doSomethingElse.<doSomethingElse_async_body> (file:///C:/code/test.dart:19:7)
#1      Future.Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:118)
<snip>
```

What's happening is that `doSomething()` is returning immediately, and then sometime later, in another context, `doSomethingElse()` is throwing its error, stopping all execution immediately. I know that an answer to this might be "Well, don't do that then." but I'm considering cases where I might not have control over the methods I'm calling (say if they are part of a library).

This situation leads to a couple of related questions:

- As the author of `main()`, is there any way I can be certain that my call to `doSomething()` won't end with an unhandled exception? Or am I dependent on the author of `doSomething()` to make sure all possible exceptions are handled or propagated to the returned Future? Is there a way to attach some sort of global error handler that can catch errors from abandoned Futures?
- As the author of `doSomething()`, if I don't want to wait on `doSomethingElse()` (say it writes to a log for example, so I neither need the output nor do I need to worry about handling errors). Is there anything I can do to prevent errors in `doSomethingElse()` from halting the program other than wrapping every call of it a try/catch block (which can be cumbersome an easily overlooked)?
- As the author of `doSomethingElse()`, is there some pattern I can use which allows me to throw Exceptions in a way that callers who wait for the Future to complete can handle that Exception themselves whereas callers that don't wait for the Future don't have to worry about catching the Exception? My best thought in that regard is to return a special object rather than throwing an Exception, but that adds a lot of extra cruft and makes the method much harder use.

Note: I'm using async/await syntax here, but the question should be equally relevant for a more strictly Future based construction (where you return a new Future in `doSomething()` instead of `.then()`ing off the one from `doSomethingElse()`

Comment: You can handle these errors with [zones](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/zones/), and there are plans to add a isolate top-level error handler, but I don't think this is implemented yet.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:isolate.Isolate#id_addErrorListener

Comment: Functions or class methods in properly implemented libraries would explicitly be synchronous or asynchronous, with only functions that really need to be asynchronous being so - just as library functions are now, returning a Future if they are asynchronous. I have not used this syntax yet but I assume editors will flag an error when they detect await/async mismatches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uncaught asynchronous errors are handled to the current zone's error handler.
What you are seeing is the root-zone's error handler reporting the error as uncaught, which also terminates the isolate.

What you want is to introduce a different error handler for your code, by running it through `runZoned` with an error handler:

```dart
import "dart:async";
main() {
  runZoned(() async {
    try {
      print("trying");
      await doSomething();
      print("success");
    } catch (e) {
      print("caught");
    }
  }, onError: (e, s) {
    print("uncaught");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [Greg pointed in its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791631/dart-errors-in-multi-level-asynchronous-code#comment43993827_27791631) you can use [Zones](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/zones/) to catch unexpected errors from async code.